# Matching a word works on www.regexr.com but not on my website

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using www.regexr.com to check my regular expressions in JavaScript.
Let's assume I have the following string:

```
/facilityservices/show/1/price_min:sdc155sd/
```

Now my task is to find price_min:sdc155sd and remove it. I wrote

```
var patterns_array = [
    'price_min:\w+'
];

var pattern = new RegExp(patterns_array.join("|"), "g");
new_url = current_url.replace(pattern, '');
```

ON the website above this RegExp matches the word. However when I checking my website it doesn't work. Where I have an error. It's too easy to make mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because RegExp escapes `\w` (as normal string) you need `\\w`.

```
var patterns_array = [
    'price_min:\\w+'
];
```

[**From the docs:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary

Also the above will work but you'll be left with two trailing slash `//` in your result you should instead apply this:

```
price_min:\\w+\/?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern doesn't work because you're creating it from a string. In this case, that's not necessary:

```
var pattern = /price_min:\w+/;
```

will do it.

When you create a regular expression from a string, you have to deal with the fact that the string grammar also thinks backslash characters (`\`) are special. Thus, by the time the RegExp constructor sees your string to interpret it as a regular expression, the backslash before the "w" will be gone.  If you need to create a regex from a string, you have to double the backslash characters:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("price_min:\\w+");
```

Again, in this particular case that's not necessary.